# Indoor tree wasn't properly watered and now it seems the top is dead, what should I do?

Tags: trees, indoors, watering, pruning

Indoor tree wasn't properly watered and now it seems the top is dead, what should I do?

Couldn't attach photos so I created a google photo album. Any help would be great thanks. I was advised to cut off the top and/or the dead foliage.  But I was hoping it would save itself.
The tree is in an office, so due to aesthetics they want a change asap, I"m trying to save the tree.

Thanks any help is much appreicated.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/FBKSZtXkBNTWb7KL8

Comment: Hi Alex, you can upload images from your phone or desktop using these instructions https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/formatting   This way the pictures will still be available even if you remove them from google

Comment: This is confusing me.  You are hoping it would save itself = do nothing, but you are asking what you should do.  If you do want to do something, why not take the (good) advice to cut out the dead?